# Округление дробного числа, в TFloatSpinEdit

Tags: delphi, vcl

Есть компонент TFloatSpinEdit (со стрелочками «вверх» «вниз») позволяющий  производить инкремент/декремент существующего числа с плавающей точкой. 
Можно ли каким-нибудь образом отменить в нем округление, при нажатии на стрелочку "вверх"?

```
Свойства компонента «Precision» = 2, «Step» = 0,01.
```

Допустим в результате каких-то расчетов появилось в этом компоненте число *«0,135573»*.
При нажатии стрелочки «вверх» у меня изменяется число на *«0,15»*, а я бы хотел чтоб получалось **«0,14»**.
Я уже пытался, до нажатия кнопки "вверх", округлять число до сотых, но пока ничего не выходит, точнее выходит *«0,15»*.

P.S.
Выдача первоначального числа «0,135573», необходима, т.к. оно в дальнейшем используется.

Comment: Ну так выводи округлённое, а используй точное.

Comment: Дело в том, что после нажатия кнопок (вверх/вниз), это число тоже будет использоваться. В принципе можно, но ... боюсь в дальнейшем неприятных ситуаций

Comment: Храните расчетные числа отдельно от интерфейса.

Comment: пришлось поиздеваться над кодом. И отдельные переменные не понадобились... Теперь, то что пользователь будет видеть в *Edit+обычный UpDown*, то и будет участвовать в расчетах...